# How to copy folder with subfolders?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

This script works perfectly in PowerShell. It copies all files with specific type. But I want copy files with it folders & subfolders.

```
$dest  = "C:\example"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\example" -Filter "*.msg" -Recurse

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $file_path = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $file.Name

    $i = 1

    while (Test-Path -Path $file_path) {
        $i++
        $file_path = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath
        "$($file.BaseName)_$($i)$($file.Extension)"
    }

    Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $file_path
}
```

Comment: Please explain in more details what functionality you would like to have. Some practical examples would be a good start.

Comment: hi for eg there are 1000 .txt files in folders. this successfully copies that but it does not that folder which contain that files.

Comment: in short, it does not copies the folder but copies the file in it.

Answer (score 56):

## PowerTip: Use PowerShell to Copy Items and Retain Folder Structure

**Source:** https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/04/powertip-use-powershell-to-copy-items-and-retain-folder-structure/

**Question:** How can I use Windows PowerShell 3.0 to copy a folder structure from a drive to a network share, and retain the original structure?

**Answer:** Use the `Copy-Item` cmdlet and specify the `–Container` switched parameter:

```
$sourceRoot = "C:\temp"
$destinationRoot = "C:\n"

Copy-Item -Path $sourceRoot -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse -Destination $destinationRoot -Container
```

Comment: can you edit my code add in it please cheers

Comment: $dest = "C:\n"
Copy-Item -Path $sourceRoot -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse -Destination $destinationRoot -Container
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Admin Support" -Filter "*.msg" -Recurse



ForEach ($file in $files) {
    
    $file_path = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $file.Name
    
    $i = 1
    
    While (Test-Path -Path $file_path) {
    
        $i++
        $file_path = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath "$($file.BaseName)_$($i)$($file.Extension)"    
    
    }
    
    Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $file_path

}

Comment: no it does work. i have added that line mate.

Comment: @greeline you don't need a loop - just use the code I provided.

Comment: oh sorry, thankyou so much.

Comment: According to the docs, `Container` is on by default: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters